# Web-parsing using BeautifulSoup with the same div - Cant return 'N/A' if not found on page

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So i'm trying to scrape this entire website but the issue is that the page uses the same  with the entries I want. So this is why I am doing the findAll for that same  then looking for the individual parameters with the if: statements.

My current issue is I cant get all the parameter to be the same length since some pages do not have that parameter. Which also means that I cannot export it to a csv if the columns arent the same length.

Also, with the current code it does not return 'N/A' when its not found.

Here's my code (might not be the most efficient either)

```
'''
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
header = soup.find('p', attrs={'class':'ho1'}).text
location.append({'Location' : header.partition(split)[2]} if header else 'N/A')
for Listing in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'style' : "height:19px; line-height:19px; color:#333; display:inline; float:left"}):
    print(Listing)
    if 'ID: ' in Listing.text:
        identification.append({'ID' : Listing.text} if Listing.text else 'N/A')
    if 'Bedrooms:' in Listing.text:
        bedrooms.append({'Bedrooms' : Listing.text} if Listing.text else 'N/A')
    if 'Bathrooms: ' in Listing.text:
        bathrooms.append({'Bathrooms' : Listing.text} if Listing.text else 'N/A')
    if 'Type: ' in Listing.text:
        typetotal.append({'Type' : Listing.text} if Listing.text else 'N/A')
```

'''

Comment: As an aside, why would you use `'N/A'` instead of None? Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Yeah newbie here! But also, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The construction:

```
{'Bedrooms' : Listing.text} if Listing.text else 'N/A'
```

will get the value `'N/A'` if `Listing.text` is `None` or if `Listing.text` is empty string. This possibility is disabled by previous `if`.

```
if 'Bedrooms:' in Listing.text:
        bedrooms.append({'Bedrooms' : Listing.text} if Listing.text else 'N/A')
```

It we enter the block after `if` then `Listing.text` is not empty.

Perhaps you mean the following:

```
bedrooms.append({'Bedrooms' : Listing.text} if 'Bedrooms:' in Listing.text else 'N/A')
```

This is still not optimal, but it is a minimal correction to your code.

**UPDATE#1**

In your new example all items are listed in one string without separators. In such a case your shoud extract the values first. For example using regular expressions.

```
import re

l_text = 'ID: 225671 Type: Apartment Size: 300 m²  Bedrooms: 3  Bathrooms: 3  '

pat_id = r'ID:\s*(\d+)'
pat_bedrooms = r'Bedrooms:\s*(\d+)'
pat_apt_size = r'Apartment Size:\s*(\d+)\s*m²'
pat_id2 = r'ID2:\s*(\d+)'

res = re.search(pat_id, l_text)
val_id = res.group(1) if res else 'N/A'

res = re.search(pat_id2, l_text)
val_id2 = res.group(1) if res else 'N/A'

res = re.search(pat_bedrooms, l_text)
val_bedrooms = res.group(1) if res else 'N/A'

res = re.search(pat_apt_size, l_text)
val_apt_size = res.group(1) if res else 'N/A'


print(val_id, val_id2, val_bedrooms, val_apt_size)
```

Output:

```
225671 N/A 3 300
```

Or you can use universal pattern:

```
pat_any = r'([A-Z][^:]*):\s*(\d+)'
res = re.findall(pat_any, l_text)
res = {k:v for k,v in res}

val_id = res.get('ID', 'N/A')
val_id2 = res.get('ID2', 'N/A')
val_bedrooms = res.get('Bedrooms', 'N/A')
val_apt_size = res.get('Apartment Size', 'N/A')

print(val_id, val_id2, val_bedrooms, val_apt_size)
```

Output:

```
225671 N/A 3 300
```

This implementation drops `m²`. If you wish to include it you can use:

```
pat_any = r'([A-Z][^:]*):\s*([^A-Z]+)'
res = re.findall(pat_any, l_text)
res = {k:v.strip() for k,v in res}

val_id = res.get('ID', 'N/A')
val_id2 = res.get('ID2', 'N/A')
val_bedrooms = res.get('Bedrooms', 'N/A')
val_apt_size = res.get('Apartment Size', 'N/A')

print(val_id, val_id2, val_bedrooms, val_apt_size)
```

Output:

```
225671 N/A 3 300 m²
```

The implementation depends on the details not shown by you.

Comment: Thanks but that does not exactly return what I intended to do. Here's an example of Listing.text below: `ID: 225671
Type: Apartment
Size: 300 m²
 Bedrooms: 3
 Bathrooms: 3
 Parking Spaces: 1
 Satellite TV
 Garden
 Gym
 Swimming Pool
 Balcony
 Security
 Pets Allowed` But sometimes these entries arent all available and I am looking for a way to compensate for that by returning 'N/A' to get all the strings the same length.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Sergey

Comment: @aalnaser You unhide a little more detail, but not all of them.